# How can I call/message on iPad air with SIM?

Tags: ios, messages, call, ipad

I have purchased an iPad Air with cellular but I cannot send and receive messages.

The name of the SIM company has appeared and I have connected it with my router. There is no icon for calling either, just an icon for messages.

Answer (score 1):

You can't without jailbreaking. The SIM for the iPad air is for the data network only. You can't make or receive phone calls, nor send or receive SMS/MMS messages.

Comment: Why is jailbreak required ?

Comment: @Buscar Because Apple don't allow it

Comment: @grgarside is correct in that a non-jailbroken iPad cannot send/receive SMS/MMS messages, but it can send iMessages. Of course, this is only of use if the people you're in contact with use Apple devices...

Answer (score 0):

I make phone calls on my iPad using Tugo app from O2, works off my O2 phone account.